# Compute $\lim_{r\rightarrow +\infty} \int_{B(0,r)} \frac{y}{1+\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^5}}$ dx dy

Tags: real-analysis

I want to compute if exists $\lim_{r\rightarrow +\infty} \int_{B(0,r)} \frac{y}{1+\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^5}}$ dx dy

I use polar coordinates and I found $4\lim_{r\rightarrow +\infty} \int_{0}^{r} \frac{\rho^2}{1+\rho^5} d\rho$.

This integral exists because $g(\rho)=\frac{\rho^2}{1+\rho^5} \sim \frac{1}{\rho^3}$ near $+\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $r>0$, 
$$
\int_{B(0,r)}\frac{y}{1+(x^{2}+y^{2})^{\frac{5}{2}}}dm(x,y)=0.
$$

Reason: By Fubini Theorem, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \int_{B(0,r)}\frac{y}{1+(x^{2}+y^{2})^{\frac{5}{2}}}dm(x,y)\\
 & = & \int_{-r}^{r}\left(\int_{-\sqrt{r^{2}-x^{2}}}^{\sqrt{r^{2}-x^{2}}}\frac{y}{1+(x^{2}+y^{2})^{\frac{5}{2}}}\,dy\right)dx\\
 & = & 0
\end{eqnarray*}
because for each $x\in[-r,r]$, $\int_{-\sqrt{r^{2}-x^{2}}}^{\sqrt{r^{2}-x^{2}}}\frac{y}{1+(x^{2}+y^{2})^{\frac{5}{2}}}\,dy=0$,
by observing that the integrand $y\mapsto\frac{y}{1+(x^{2}+y^{2})^{\frac{5}{2}}}$ is an odd function.

Comment: The existence is right as I do up?

Comment: Before taking limit $r\rightarrow \infty$, the integral exists because we are integrating a continuous function over a compact set.

Comment: For each $r>0$, the integral is zero. Obviously, the limit by taking $r\rightarrow\infty$ is also zero.

Comment: If I want compute $\int_{R^2} f(x,y) dx dy $ can I use the same strategy or is it different?

Comment: It is not necessarily to consider polar coordinate transformation. However, it is also possible to do so. In that case, $y=r \sin \theta$.

Comment: For integral over the whole plane $\mathbb{R^2}$, there are more than one definition of "integrability". The strictest one is "absolutely integrable" (many people simply call it integrable), in the sense that $\int\int |f(x,y)| dxdy <\infty$. For simplicity, let us consider the one-dimensional analog. Absolutely integrable requires that $\int |f(x)| dx< \infty$. However, it may happen that although $\int |f(x)| dx=\infty$, $\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty} \int_{-a}^a f(x) dx$ exists and is finite.

Comment: The later one is called Cauchy principal value. Absolutely integrable functions share a lot of nice properties but the later one does not have. You may compare absolutely convergent series and conditionally convergent series. Conditionally convergent series converges due to cancellation of positive terms and negative terms. However, both positive terms and negative terms sum up to infinity. Such series lacks many good properties. If you need to deal with it, you need to pay extra attention to avoid committing logical fallacy.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that converting from $(x,y)$ to $(\rho,\theta)$ we have $x=\rho\cos\theta$ and $y=\rho\sin\theta$, and the determinant of the Jacobian of this transformation is $\rho$. Thus, using Fubini's theorem and polar coordinates, we have that, for any $r>0$
\begin{align*}\int_{B(0,r)} \frac{y}{1+\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^5}} dx dy&=\int_0^r\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\rho^2\sin\theta}{1+\rho^5}d\theta d\rho \\
&=\int_0^r\frac{\rho^2}{1+\rho^5}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin\theta d\theta d\rho\\
& =0,
\end{align*}
where the last equality follows because $\sin$ is odd so the inner integral is $0$. As this is true for all $r>0$ the limit must be $0$ too.